# Git wont push. Asking for user/pass

Tags: github

I'm trying to push some of my projects to my github account but when i try it wont let me. I was able to push just a couple of days ago and now I cant. 
I tried 
running

```
    cd existing_git_repo
    git remote add origin https://github.com/Ommy/MapTool.git
    git push -u origin master
```

but on git bash it asks for

```
    Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I try my username/password which doesn't work.

I tried running

```
     git config --global user.name "Fasih Awan"
     git config --global user.email *********@gmail.com
```

but even with that it still asks for the username/password. I created the repository on github before pushing but it still does this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using HTTP for the remote repository you will still need to type your username and password. If you want to use SSH keys, use the SSH protocol for the remote repository. There is a guide [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) on how to configure SSH keys.

Comment: I went through the setup but it still won't let me. This is weird because just a couple of days ago I could push

Comment: Did you change your remote from HTTPS to SSH? It will normally be of the format   `git remote add origin git@github.com:Ommy/MapTool.git`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, which said that it already exists. So then i tried pushing but got the same response

Comment: Did you first remove the HTTPS remote? `git remote rm origin`

Comment: With that I ran        "git push origin master --force" which worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Either use password caching or SSH. It's all nicely explained here: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

Comment: I tried password caching and also running through the SSH setup. It still asks for the same credentials. it just says src refspec master does not match any

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have uploaded your public key to github. The only thing you should be asked for is a password for you public key, not a username.